# How to nest an expression or quote in another expression or quote?

Tags: r, expression, apollo, nest, quote

Let's say I have

```
first <- quote(beta_a*a + beta_b*b)
second <- quote(beta_d*d + beta_e*e)
third <- quote(first + second)
```

I want `third` to return `beta_a*a + beta_b*b + beta_d*d + beta_e*e` but instead it returns `first + second`

Desired result:

```
third
> beta_a*a + beta_b*b + beta_d*d + beta_e*e
```

I know that it makes sense that it then returns `first + second`, but what can I do to get the desired result?

For context, imagine that I need to use this for a specification for an ordered logit model in Apollo. Each first and second type is a variable, and the content is the dummies for that variable. Third then represents a specification. Imagine then I have 10+ variables with 10+ dummies each and I have to make a specification for each combination of variables. It's a lot of manual labour to write out all these utility functions. If I could make the specifications beforehand by condensing first the dummies to variables and then the variables to specifications, it would save me a lot of lines of code and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `substitute`:

```r
first <- quote(beta_a*a + beta_b*b)
second <- quote(beta_d*d + beta_e*e)
substitute(a + b, list(a = first, b = second))
#beta_a * a + beta_b * b + (beta_d * d + beta_e * e)
```

Comment: If I use `expression` instead of `quote`, can I make the `third` a bit more clean?

Comment: You can use `paste(first, second, collapse = " + ")` if they are expressions

Answer (score 0):

With `bquote`:

```r
first <- quote(beta_a*a + beta_b*b)
second <- quote(beta_d*d + beta_e*e)
bquote(.(first) + .(second))
# beta_a * a + beta_b * b + (beta_d * d + beta_e * e)
```